# make selected item in select box using angularjs with dynamic data

Tags: angularjs

In html page i take one select box and put data in them by fetching records from databases like that..

```
<select id="category" ng-model="eventAdd.data.selCategory" ng-change="changeBg(eventAdd.data.selCategory)">
   <option value="">-Select-</option>
   <option ng-repeat="photo in photos"
           value="{{photo.PhotoId}}">
           {{photo.Category}}
   </option>
   <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
```

In select box i add one option "Other" if user select that option i will show one input box there user can enter custom name and i will push it $scope.photos and it will display in selectbox but it can be not be selected.

```
Photo.allCategory().then(function(photos)
{
    $timeout(function() 
    {
        $scope.photos = photos;
    },0);
});


$scope.changeBg = function(val)
{
    if(val=="other")
    {
        $cordovaDialogs.prompt('Category name', 'Category', ['Ok','Cancel'], '')
        .then(function(result) 
        {
            console.log("call");
            var input = result['input1'];
            $scope.photos.push({photoId:9,Category:input});
            $scope.eventAdd.data.selCategory = 8;
        });
    }
}
```

Using this line

```
$scope.eventAdd.data.selCategory = 3;
```

Third i item can be selected but when i am doing like

```
$scope.eventAdd.data.selCategory = $scope.photos.length;
```

It cannot be selected which last one added by in prompt.

Please check by codepan

http://codepen.io/pareshgami/pen/BooEap

Please help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you mean. A few things though: the HTML uses `PhotoId`, whereas the code used `photoId`. I don't understand why you set selCategory to 8 if you want the new photo to be selected, since its ID is 9. I also don't understand why you would use $scope.photos.length. It's irrelevant. What matters is the ID of the photo to select.

Comment: I am doing length because if list have 10 item then if i am add new item in list so i give length

Comment: Let me explain in details. if in list have 3 item then i am give $scope.eventAdd.data.selCategory = 4 and i am add new item so now list have 4 item so $scope.eventAdd.data.selCategory = 4 this will work but i will not work if i am add again new item then $scope.eventAdd.data.selCategory = 4 it will select previous entered item

Comment: @JB Nizet can you check please http://codepen.io/pareshgami/pen/BooEap